# Istio Ingress does not work - only port forwarding works

Tags: azure, kubernetes-ingress, istio, azure-aks

[image]I am trying to follow the istio docs on deploying the bookinfo app and setting up ingress controllers at - https://istio.io/docs/tasks/traffic-management/ingress/ingress-control/#determining-the-ingress-ip-and-ports

After creating an istio gateway as -

```
**kubectl apply -n my-bookinfo -f gateway.yaml**

apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: Gateway
metadata:
  name: httpbin-gateway
spec:
  selector:
    istio: ingressgateway # use Istio default gateway implementation
  servers:
  - port:
      number: 80
      name: http
      protocol: HTTP
    hosts:
    - "httpbin.example.com"
```

Response: *gateway.networking.istio.io/httpbin-gateway configured*

when I try to view it as -

```
kubectl get gateway -n my-bookinfo
```

I dont any resources back, instead I get - "*No resources found*"

What am I missing here? Should I not be able to see the gateway resources? I am not even sure that they got created. How do I validate it?

Comment: this looks weird, can you do `kubectl get gateway --all-namespaces` and check if its there somewhere?

Comment: Did that too, no luck. Could it be something in my cloud network that is preventing it?

Comment: you sure your command completes successfully? what if you do apply and get right after that?

Comment: The message I get right after applying the yaml is - 

gateway.networking.istio.io/httpbin-gateway configured

Same response if I do a get right after.

Comment: you are getting the response it is configured when doing the kubectl get? share the screenshot please

Comment: I should have clarified. I meant, I get the same "No resources found" message. I have added a screenshot to the question.

Comment: what if you do `kubectl get gateway.networking.istio.io --all-namespaces`?

Comment: That worked! Damn i should have tried that too!

Comment: thats weird, it should work without that? what is your kubectl version? or you probably have another resource that is called gateway in the kubernetes?

Comment: Client Version: v1.16.0
Server Version: v1.14.6

And I dont think that I have any other resource with the same name. I did kubectl get all on my namespace.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in this case the solution is to use the full resource api name:

```
kubectl get gateway.networking.istio.io -n my-bookinfo
```